# Android - Trying to instantiate a class that is not a fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

So I'm trying to create a fragment in my app that contains a toolbar (as an action bar) using appcompat activity so I can reuse it across multiple views.

I've tested a simple text-only fragment using a class that extends fragment only and got that to work, but to include a toolbar I need to extend **AppCompatActivity** in the view (I think).

When I try to get this to work, I get an error that says that my `action_bar_fragment` is not a `Fragment`.

I fell like I'm missing something basic here. Any ideas?

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.aaron.personaldataassistant;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // action_bar_fragment = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_fragment);
       // setSupportActionBar(action_bar_fragment);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater mi=getMenuInflater();
        mi.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Main Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.aaron.personaldataassistant.MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.aaron.personaldataassistant.action_bar_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/action_bar_fragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Action Bar Fragment:

```
package com.example.aaron.personaldataassistant;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class action_bar_fragment extends AppCompatActivity {

    public action_bar_fragment() {
    }

    Toolbar action_bar;

    @Nullable

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_fragment, container, false);

    }


        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.action_bar_fragment);


            action_bar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
            setSupportActionBar(action_bar);
        }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
        mi.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int i = item.getItemId();

        if (i == R.id.item1) {

            Toast.makeText(action_bar_fragment.this, "Item 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (i == R.id.item2) {

            Toast.makeText(action_bar_fragment.this, "Item 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (i == R.id.item3) {

            Toast.makeText(action_bar_fragment.this, "Item 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
//replace toasts with desired actions: Settings, Help and Exit. Settigns is blank, help is context-dependent, exit gives possibility to exit


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Fragment Layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="layout.Fragment_1">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/action_bar"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

And of course the error message:

```
  --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.aaron.personaldataassistant, PID: 2481
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aaron.personaldataassistant/com.example.aaron.personaldataassistant.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
                   Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.example.aaron.personaldataassistant.action_bar_fragment that is not a Fragment
                      at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:617)
                      at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:593)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2302)
                      at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
                      at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5884)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:36)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                      at com.example.aaron.personaldataassistant.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
                      at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:618)
                      at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:593) 
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2302) 
                      at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98) 
                      at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5884) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:36) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                      at com.example.aaron.personaldataassistant.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
Application terminated.
```

Thank you for your time.

---

**UPDATE**

This is great, the top answer helped me figure out that doing things in a fragment can require different methods than doing them in an Activity. Googling "How do I do X in a fragment" turned out to give me almost everything I needed.  There is only one problem left now: I changed the Action Bar Fragment line 37 to

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
action_bar = (Toolbar) getView().findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
```

This is giving me a null object reference, but the layout definitely exists! Any idea what's going on?

The relevant part of the error message is:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Sorry for the long delay getting back to you, I had work. Should be faster this time!

I will also clean up the comment I made on your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your *intended* fragment is not a Fragment but an Activity, where:

```
action_bar_fragment extends AppCompatActivity {

}
```

is an Activity, so you should be extends `action_bar_fragment` with Fragment:

```
action_bar_fragment extends Fragment {

}
```

And please change your code style, where `action_bar_fragment` should be something like `ActionBarFragment`. A class name should be started with uppercase.

Please read [Creating and Using Fragments](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments).

Comment: This is great, it turn out that methods for doing things in a Fragment can be completely different from doing them in an Activity, so googling "How do I do X in a Fragment" got me most of the info I needed. Except now I have this weird NullPointerException and I'm not sure why. Details are in the bottom of the main question. Any ideas?

Comment: This could be because you haven't inflate the layout in `onCreateView()` of fragment. like:
`@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_some, parent, false);
    }`

Comment: Or you don't have `action_bar` in your layout

Comment: I've figured what I need to do - instead of using a Fragment, I'll put the action bar I need in a parent Activity and extend it to other Activities as needed. Much simpler! Thanks for your help with the Fragments, it helped me learn a lot about them.

Answer (score 5):

I came upon this question because of the main title "Trying to instantiate a class that is not a Fragment". So maybe my solution can help. I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3 and targeting API 15.

I got that error:

```
...
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.xyz.tuv.MyFragment that is not a Fragment
```

because I was importing:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

instead of

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

Since API 11, you can use a regular activity (`android.app.Activity`) for inserting fragments as documented [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html). But in that case you also have to use `android.app.Fragment`, contrary to what the [main example](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#Create) shows.

Comment: Happened to me as well after creating a list fragment from an Android Studio template. Renaming the import worked.

Answer (score -1):

In your MainActivity class, you have to change the order of some of code, they are:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater mi=getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Change it to :

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
  mi.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
  return true;
```

}

and try again.

Comment: Hmmm! Are you serious bro?